# Calling history.pushState() inside a new document created by document.write() causes SecurityError on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Take the following code, and serve it *through a web server* such as `http-server` (Node package). I have an example server up [here](https://hichris.com/ietest.html).

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="max-age=0"/>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    document.write('<script>history.pushState(null, null, "bar.html");console.log("passed");\u003c/script>');
}
</script>
```

*Note that the `Cache-Control` header is there because IE aggressively caches the page for some reason. This helped me during my testing, but not necessary to reproduce the issue.*

When I load the page in IE11 (Windows 10), I get a `SecurityError` printed to the console, no URL change, and no "passed" printed.

In Edge 16, I get "passed" printed to the console, but no URL change.

In Firefox and Chrome, this works fine: the URL changes and I get "passed" printed to the console.

Why does IE behave this way, and how can I use `document.write()` in conjunction with `pushState()`? My intention is to overwrite the entire document, not simply append to it (this is why I use `window.onload`).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add Try...Catch in your code and then try to make a test with IE11.

```html
<html>
<body>
<script>
try {
history.pushState(null, null,"bar.html");
console.log("passed");
}
catch(err) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = err.message;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This answer does not use `document.write()` nor `window.onload` as stated in my question.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody ever has the same problem, there is a workaround to fix this in IE11.

Just do a `location.href = location.href + '#fix-ie'` to change the URL without reloading the page. This has to be done right at the start, before anything else has the chance to do a `history.pushState` or a `history.replaceState`.

This seems to "move" the `location.href` over into the new document.

Full code:

```
let original = location.href;
if (original.indexOf('#') === -1) {
    location.href = original + '#ie-fix';
    location.href = original + '#';
} else {
    location.href = original + 'ie-fix';
    location.href = original;
}
```